# Does this code use good Python practices for a context-free grammar implementation?

Tags: python

I'm completing exercises in *Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools (2nd Edition)* in Python. The following code converts:

```
{ int x; char y; { bool y; x; y; } x; y; }
```

to:

```
{ { x:int; y:bool; } x:int; y:char; }
```

I had the following concerns about my code:

1. Is it acceptable to do `list(tokenize(...))` instead of using it like a proper iterator? I think it would be more efficient, but I wanted the flexibility of an array so that I could traverse backward and forward through the tokens.
2. Does it make sense to handle the control flow of the application by using Exceptions? I decided to use exceptions and rewinding instead of sentinels and peeking forward. I'm not sure if this is the best way though.

I'm not really concerned about the `tokenize` function as much, since I'm already aware of the problems there.

I would be open to any other suggestions or ways I could make this more Pythonistic.

```
class exercise(object):
    """
    program -> block
    block   -> { decls stmts }
    decls   -> decls decl
             | ∅
    decl    -> type id ;
    stmts   -> stmts stmt 
             | ∅
    stmt    -> block 
             | factor ;
    factor  -> id
    """

    def __init__(self, target):
        self.at = 0
        self.tokens = list(tokenize(target))
        self.writer = []
        self.symbols = symboltable()

    def match(self, value=None, type='symbol'):
        token = self.tokens[self.at]
        t_type, t_value = token
        if t_type != type or (value and t_value != value):
            raise InvalidSyntax('Expected {0} "{1}" but received {2} "{3}"'. \
                format(type, value, t_type, t_value))
        self.at += 1
        return token

    def parse(self):
        self.writer = []
        self.Program()
        return ' '.join(self.writer)

    def snapshot(self):
        return (self.at, len(self.writer))

    def rewind(self, snapshot):
        old_at, old_writer_len = snapshot
        self.at = old_at
        self.writer = self.writer[:old_writer_len]

    def Program(self):
        self.Block()

    def Block(self):
        self.match('{')
        self.writer.append('{')
        self.symbols = symboltable(self.symbols)
        try:
            self.Decls()
        except ParsingComplete:
            pass
        try:
            self.Stmts()
        except ParsingComplete:
            pass
        self.match('}')
        self.writer.append('}')
        self.symbols = self.symbols.parent

    def Decls(self):
        self.Decls_b()
        #self.Decl()

    def Decls_b(self):
        self.Decl()
        self.Decls()

    def Decl(self):
        snapshot = self.snapshot()
        try:
            _, type = self.match(type='word')
            _, id = self.match(type='word')
            self.symbols.put(id, type)
            self.match(';')
            return
        except:
            self.rewind(snapshot)
        raise ParsingComplete()

    def Stmts(self):
        self.Stmts_b()
        #self.Stmt()

    def Stmts_b(self):
        self.Stmt()
        self.Stmts()

    def Stmt(self):
        snapshot = self.snapshot()
        try:
            self.Block()
            return
        except:
            self.rewind(snapshot)
        try:
            self.Factor()
            self.match(';')
            return
        except:
            self.rewind(snapshot)
        raise ParsingComplete()

    def Factor(self):
        _, id = self.match(type='word')
        type = self.symbols.get(id)
        if not type:
            type = 'undeclared'
        self.writer.append('{0}:{1};'.format(id, type))

class InvalidSyntax(Exception):
    pass

class ParsingComplete(Exception):
    pass

class symboltable(object):
    """ Store lexeme name and value information for a given scope """

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        self.table = dict()

    def get(self, key):
        if key in self.table:
            return self.table[key]
        if not self.parent:
            return None
        return self.parent.get(key)

    def put(self, key, value):
        self.table.update({key: value})

def tokenize(target):
    i = 0
    while i < len(target):
        c = target[i]
        if c == ' ':
            pass
        elif c.isdigit():
            n = 0
            while True:
                n = n * 10 + int(c)
                c = target[i + 1]
                if not c.isdigit():
                    break
                i += 1
            yield ('number', n)
        elif c.isalpha():
            letters = []
            while True:
                letters.append(c)
                c = target[i + 1]
                if not c.isalpha() and not c.isdigit():
                    break
                i += 1
            word = ''.join(letters)
            yield ('word', word)
        else:
            yield('symbol', c)
        i += 1

input = '{ int x; char y; { bool y; x; y; } x; y; }'
expected = '{ { x:int; y:bool; } x:int; y:char; }'
actual = exercise(input).parse()
assert actual == expected
```

Comment: It may be worth looking into pylint and pychecker, there are a number of quick fixes and small errors that come up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class exercise(object):
```

The python style guide recommends CamelCase for class names

```
    """
    program -> block
    block   -> { decls stmts }
    decls   -> decls decl
             | ∅
    decl    -> type id ;
    stmts   -> stmts stmt 
             | ∅
    stmt    -> block 
             | factor ;
    factor  -> id
    """

    def __init__(self, target):
        self.at = 0
        self.tokens = list(tokenize(target))
```

This is perfectly fine. It's probably faster this way, but will take more memory.

```
        self.writer = []
        self.symbols = symboltable()

    def match(self, value=None, type='symbol'):
        token = self.tokens[self.at]
        t_type, t_value = token
        if t_type != type or (value and t_value != value):
```

For checking if value is None, I recommend `value is None` rather then just checking for false. Another false value could be passed

```
            raise InvalidSyntax('Expected {0} "{1}" but received {2} "{3}"'. \
                format(type, value, t_type, t_value))
        self.at += 1
        return token
```

I would actually separate `match`, `snapshot` and, `rewind` off onto their own class. Those form a unit of logic of operating over the token stream, and are best kept separate from the actual parsing logic.

```
    def parse(self):
        self.writer = []
```

This attribute bothers me. I wonder if the code would be cleaner to use return values for this. The name is also a little bit off because its hold data, it doesn't really write anything itself.

```
        self.Program()
        return ' '.join(self.writer)

    def snapshot(self):
        return (self.at, len(self.writer))

    def rewind(self, snapshot):
        old_at, old_writer_len = snapshot
        self.at = old_at
        self.writer = self.writer[:old_writer_len]
```

It may be better to `del` the extra stuff in writer, rather then slice it

```
    def Program(self):
```

Python convention is to have lowercase_with_underscores for method names. This method is also internal to the parser and should perhaps begin with an underscore.

```
        self.Block()

    def Block(self):
        self.match('{')
        self.writer.append('{')
        self.symbols = symboltable(self.symbols)
        try:
            self.Decls()
        except ParsingComplete:
            pass
```

Using an exception to say something is finished will be severely looked down upon

```
        try:
            self.Stmts()
        except ParsingComplete:
            pass
        self.match('}')
        self.writer.append('}')
        self.symbols = self.symbols.parent

    def Decls(self):
        self.Decls_b()
        #self.Decl()
```

There isn't a whole lot of point to a function that just calls another function

```
    def Decls_b(self):
        self.Decl()
        self.Decls()
```

I would suggest that you use a loop rather then recursion here, and that you handle the exception here. This is the point where a Decl is either Decl Decls or nothing. So here is the best place to have the logic diverge. Something lile

```
def Decls(self):
   while True:
       try:
           snapshot = self.snapshot()
           self.Decl() # try parsing another Decl
       except InvalidSyntaxError:
           self.rewind(snapshot)
           break # if we failed to parse the Decl, stop
```

I think using the looping constructs of the language make this much clearer. However, this points to a problem with your approach. Pretty much every single syntax error will be diagnosed as a missing `}`, not a very helpful error message. This is because most failure exceptions gets interpreted having attempted to parse the wrong thing.

```
    def Decl(self):
        snapshot = self.snapshot()
        try:
            _, type = self.match(type='word')
            _, id = self.match(type='word')
            self.symbols.put(id, type)
            self.match(';')
            return
        except:
```

Don't do this. You should catch only the specific type of exception you are interested in. Otherwise you'll catch other exceptions and make bugs hard to find.

```
            self.rewind(snapshot)
        raise ParsingComplete()
```

This is only executed in the case of an exception, so why isn't it in the exception block?

[Snip Stmt section, similar issues apply]

```
class InvalidSyntax(Exception):
    pass

class ParsingComplete(Exception):
    pass

class symboltable(object):
    """ Store lexeme name and value information for a given scope """

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        self.table = dict()

    def get(self, key):
        if key in self.table:
            return self.table[key]
```

This is considered a bad idea in python because you have to lookup the key twice

```
        if not self.parent:
            return None
```

Do you really want to return None? Shouldn't you throw an exception?

```
        return self.parent.get(key)
```

I'd write this as

```
try:
   return self.table[key]
except KeyError:
   if self.parent is None:
       raise UnknownVariableError(key)
   else:
       return self.parent.get(key)
```

I think it is clearer

```
    def put(self, key, value):
        self.table.update({key: value})
```

Why not `self.table[key] = value`?

[skipped tokenize]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll be improving my code with some of these suggestions. Decls_b only exists because I wanted to express "decls -> decls decl" which is defined in the grammar, but using a loop instead will actually simplify the code and make it easier to understand. The "writer" is actually a convention from .NET I'm using even though it isn't intuitive here. It's supposed to represent the semantic action for each production rule.

Comment: I agree using exceptions to handle control flow does obscure syntax errors... I'll try to fix that. Though I'm less than 1/7th of the way through this book and it hasn't really covered error handling in-depth. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I'll post the updated code later if I can fix the syntax errors. Another improvement I made, beyond these suggestions, was to use a namedtuple for tokens so I don't have to unpack every time to retrieve the token value.